# How does one automatically run a function when any error message appears?

Tags: autocmd, external-command, error

I would like to play sounds for accessibility reasons. Do I need to patch and compile (neo)vim to provide some sort of `OnError` autocmd?

**edit:** more generically I'm looking for a way to hook into console dialog so that speech synthesis can be used. `confirm()`'s optional `{type}` argument could also be of better use by playing an appropriate sound for error,info,warning or generic messages.

Comment: not possible. I made a [patch](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/master/error_aucmd) a couple of years ago, but Bram did not like to include it, although this topic has come up several times in the past before

Comment: and a further discussion on that patch on [vim-dev](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/3_Mn38Jk3N0/W3TQ0g1WDQAJ) with I think a newer patch

Comment: thanks for the links. (it's not quite the easiest keyword to google)